# Passing multiple values in JSP url

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to pass multiple values in a JSP page url to another one.
The code is:

```
<form name="QuantityForm" onsubmit="return quantityValidation()" action='<%="basket.jsp?addItem="+product.PID%>' method="post">
        Quantity <input type="text" name="quantity" size="5">
        <input class="button button2" type="submit" value="Add to basket" />    
</form>
```

How do i pass the value of `quantity`(the field of `name="quantity"`) in the same URL? i know it's something like `"Search.jsp?item=<%=search%>&item2=value2&item3=value3.."` but i can't seem to structure it properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your ? and parameters in the action url. Put your parameters in input tags:

```
<form name="QuantityForm" onsubmit="return quantityValidation()" action='basket.jsp' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="addItem" value="%product.PID%">
        Quantity <input type="text" name="quantity" size="5">
        <input class="button button2" type="submit" value="Add to basket" />    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using `method="post"` which doesn't allow parameters to be passed into the url. change it to `method="get"` if you want the parameters to be passed along with the url.